# JSF ClassCastException while preparing data in bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, classcastexception, selectmanylistbox

I'm just trying out JSF an ran into an ugly `ClassCastException`.

I have a Managed Bean (`CustomerBean`) that has a POJO (`Customer`) where I store the user data. One of the POJO's properties is `List<CathegoryType.Type> preferredCathegories` (with getter and setter). `CathegoryType` is a model class which provides cathegories (through a nested `enum Type`) and their localized names (through a method `getCathegory(Type type)`).

Now, I have one JSF page to enter some user data (`editCustomer.xhtml`). There is a section to select preferred cathegories. The JSF code to select the cathegories looks like this:

```
<h:selectManyListbox 
        id="pcat"
        value="#{customerBean.customer.preferredCathegories}"
        styleClass="form-control">
    <f:selectItems 
            value="#{customerBean.cathegoryTypes}">
    </f:selectItems>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

The renderes component looks like this:
[image: The renderes <code>selectMAnyListBox</code>]

The field `List<SelectItem> CustomerBeand.cathegoryTypes` provides the mapping of the enum literals to their names like `new SelectItem(type, CathegoryType.getCathegory(type))`. Now there comes the tricky part that throws the `ClassCastException` (in my understanding for no reason!)

When I submit the form an other JSF page (`showCustomer.xhtml`) is should present the just entered user data. But creating the view terminates with throwing the following ClassCastException:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/...] threw exception [java.lang.String cannot be cast to ...CathegoryType$Type] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to ...CathegoryType$Type
    at ...CustomerBean.getNamedPreferredCathegories(CustomerBean.java:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

To present the chosen cathegories, `showCustomer.xhtml` calls a method `String CustomerBean.getNamedPreferredCathegories()`:

```
<h:outputText value="#{customerBean.namedPreferredCathegories}" />
```

This method calculates a `String` of the chosen cathegories:

```
def String getNamedPreferredCathegories() {
    val StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder
    val List<CathegoryType.Type> cathegories = customer.preferredCathegories
    val ListIterator<CathegoryType.Type> iter = cathegories.listIterator
    var boolean first = true
    while (iter.hasNext) {
        val CathegoryType.Type cat = iter.next
        val String name = cathegoryType.getCathegory(cat)
        if(first) first = false else names.append(', ')
        names.append(name)
    }
    return names.toString
}
```

I'm using the *Xtend* programming languate. It is a JVM language (compiles to Java code) and thus fully compatible with the *Java typesystem*. I tried to write this method as Java like as possible, normally it can be done in one single line:

```
def String getNamedPreferredCathegories() {
    '''«FOR name : customer.preferredCathegories.map[cathegory] SEPARATOR ', '»«name»«ENDFOR»'''.toString
}
```

Since I do any iteration over the list, the `ClassCastException` is thrown ... but as one can see, I do not perform any cast operation in my code! So where does the exception comes from?

I run the project on Tomcat 8.5.9.

**Edit:**
Ok, the generated Java method of my Xtend method is theo following:

```
public String getNamedPreferredCathegories() {
    final StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
    final List<CathegoryType.Type> cathegories = this.customer.getPreferredCathegories();
    final ListIterator<CathegoryType.Type> iter = cathegories.listIterator();
    boolean first = true;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        {
            final CathegoryType.Type cat = iter.next(); // Exception is thrown here!
            final String name = this.cathegoryType.getCathegory(cat);
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                names.append(", ");
            }
            names.append(name);
        }
    }
    return names.toString();
}
```

The exception is thrown in the marked line (`final CathegoryType.Type cat = iter.next();`). Additionally the generated Java parts of the related `Customer` class are this:

```
public class Customer {

    private List<CathegoryType.Type> preferredCathegories;

    public List<CathegoryType.Type> getPreferredCathegories() {
        return this.preferredCathegories;
    }

    public void setPreferredCathegories(final List<CathegoryType.Type> preferredCathegories) {
        this.preferredCathegories = preferredCathegories;
    }
}
```

Additionally, I will have a look at the linked question that might discuss the exact same problem.

Comment: You might want to share the generated .java for that .xtend, at least the part that creates line 247. My first guess is that customer.preferredCategories actually returns a "poluted" List that contains (at least some) Strings instead of CathegoryType.Type.

Comment: Ok, k5_, I added the requested Java code snippets for you, but, as you can see, my question is a duplicate. I looked the linked question an got an answer. Thanks BalusC for your advice!